# Devise timedout error showing `true`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When my session expired, Devise is giving me a nonsense error like below:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

How do I customize it so it doesn't show the `true` error?

Answer (score 11):

Yep, it was [reported in github devise repo](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1777), and they update the readme about that.

I solve it in my app with a code like this:

```
 <% [:notice, :error, :alert].each do |level| %>
    <% unless flash[level].blank? %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= flash_class(level) %> fade in">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">X</button>
        <%= content_tag :p, flash[level] %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

You could also just check to see if the value is_a?(String) before displaying it.